# How can I make removeChild() work like unloadAndStop()?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I'm building an "interactive book" using Flash and Air for iOS, and have VERY little AS3 experience...

I had planned to load "pages" in as external SWFs then banish them with unloadAndStop - so that each time a user "turned the page" the SWF loaded in and the nested mini-games in those pages would play "fresh" for the first time. Well - apparently reloaded SWFs are a no-go for AIR and iOS.

I suppose I'm left with replacing those external SWFS with Internal MCs and using AddChild / RemoveChild - but that doesn't reset the variables so that the mini-games play fresh and I'm a little too green to know a better solution.

Is there any way to beef up RemoveChild so the MC loads "fresh" every time I put it on stage?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: is your "interactive book" free for all to use? if yes, where you will release it?

Answer (score 0):

if you you added movie clip by time line, just rename its instance name from property panel, then new instance of MovieClip created in that frame.

if you want to add it by AS3, you must set a linkage for it first, a class name which would start by a letter (recommended capital letter)

[image]

and then :

```
var mc:MovieClip = new Game1();
addChild(mc);
```

when you removed it, to adding it again with refreshed properties (as you said)
you must do:

```
mc = new Game1(); // make a new instance of Game1
addChild(mc);
```

### Edit

note: for saving performance, after calling `removeChild` freeze your movieclip and make it ready for garbaging by removing its eventListeners, dont scare :d
tke a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307598/garbage-collection-best-practices) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090971/how-does-flash-handle-garbage-collection-when-it-comes-to-adding-movieclips-dire) (i just find this refrences by fast searching but i now they are helpful)

Comment: Ye gods! That worked! Thanks, Payam! (I'm still not 100% clear on the garbage removal, but I'll dig deeper on that now!) Many, many thanks!